# Are there infinitely many semi primes of the form $x^2 + 2x$ for integral $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, open-problem

My professor showed the class 1000 dollars and said he'd give it to whoever could prove it... Obviously he's not serious but in having a tough time wrestling with this problem.

Comment: I will tell you the answer for \$999. (joke)

Comment: Please do... I'm very curious

Comment: Fueling the interest of a problem by offering money if one knows that there is no solution (or boils down to an unsolved problem) is debatable in the ehtical sense, but often works well. I remember the fifteen-puzzle, where the inventor offered a large prize for solving an unsolvable problem. In the case of the professor, it is a harmless joke. I do not want judge what it was in the case of the fifteen-puzzle.

Answer (score 7):

It is likely that no one in the class will collect. Since $x^2+2x=x(x+2)$, for $x\gt 2$ we have $x^2+2x$ is semiprime if and only if $x$ and $x+2$ are twin primes. Whether there are infinitely many twin primes is a longstanding [open problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime)

**Remark:** From a professional point of view, the interesting part is that the professor has $\$1000$ to show. Perhaps an inheritance.

Comment: I am so stupid for not realizing that... Thank you tough

Comment: Though not tough

Comment: As for the cash idk... It looked like real money if you ask me.. It was in 100 dollar bills

Comment: There is a very nice short storywritten about 1954, in which Fermat's Last Theorem takes the place of the Twin Primes conjecture, long before FLT was proved. I was able to find a free pdf online, "The Devil and Simon Flagg" by Arthur Porges.

Comment: The typesetting is not so good. Also, near the top of the second page, it should actually read "Include my wife in that" where they mistakenly changed the 'w' to an 'l'

Comment: Scott Aaronson put $200,000 down in a similar situation http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=456 so it's not that absurd that the professor would offer $1000. As he said: "I’ve literally bet my house on it."